# Register rest field for specific user

Tags: custom-field, users, user-roles, rest-api

I'm extending Wordpress REST API with a custom plugin, and I'm in the need of adding a new field to the user response.

The problem is that this field has to appear only in base of the user role.

For example I want a field `custom_field` appear in the response only if the user is `administrator` and not `contributor`.

At the moment I'm using the `register_rest_field()` function, but it allows me to chose only the type of object.

Do you know if there is a workaround to this issue? Or do you know better ways to reach the same result?

P.S. I'm using WP 4.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better workaround using the same filter suggested by @ben-casey in [his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259592/109855).

Firstly I registered throuhg `register_rest_field` all the custom fields of all the user types I have in the database.

Then in `rest_prepare_user`, insted adding the wanted fields, I removed the unwanted ones. In this way I can still use the same endpoint to update the field.

Below an example of the JSON clean up.

```
function my_rest_prepare_user( WP_REST_Response $response, WP_User $user, WP_REST_Request $request ){

    if( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ){

        $data = $response->get_data();

        unset($data['custom_field']);

        $response->set_data( $data );

    }

    return $response;

}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_user', 'my_rest_prepare_user', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `rest_prepare_user`

Something like this should do the trick I think.

```
function my_rest_prepare_user( WP_REST_Response $response, WP_User $user, WP_REST_Request $request ){

    if( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ){

        $data = $response->get_data();

        $data['custom_field'] = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'custom_field', true );

        $response->set_data( $data );

    }

    return $response;

}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_user', 'my_rest_prepare_user', 10, 3 );
```

**EDIT**

If you need to update the user you can register a custom route

```
function yoursite_update_user( WP_REST_Request $request ){

    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $request->get_param( 'id' ) );

    if( $user && in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ){

        $value = $request->get_param( 'my_field' );

        update_user_meta( $request->get_param( 'id' ), 'my_field', $value );

        return new WP_REST_Response( [
            'code'    => 'user_updated',
            'message' =>  'User Updated'
        ], 200 );

    } else {

        return new WP_REST_Response( [
            'code'    => 'invalid_user',
            'message' =>  'Invalid user'
        ], 404 );

    }

}

register_rest_route( 'yoursite/v1', '/users/update_my_field/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
    'callback'            => 'yoursite_update_user',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_users' );
    },
    'args'                => array(
        'id' => array(
            'validate_callback' => function ( $param, $request, $key ) {
                return is_numeric( $param );
            }
        ),
    ),
) );
```

The above route would be triggered by an authenticated `POST` request to: `http:://yoursite.com/wp-json/yoursite/v1/users/update_my_field/{USER_ID}` with a post field of `my_field`

Comment: It works! But how can I handle the UPDATE call if I don't register the field?

Comment: @MicheleFortunato I have added an example of a custom route to update the user.

Comment: I would have preferred to stick to the WP REST structure. Adding an endpoint only to handle the update it's a quite dirty workaround in my opinion.
I'll wait to see if someone has better solutions in mind before accepting the answer.
If there's nothing suitable in the WP core, maybe someone should suggest to implement this feature. It's not uncommon to have different types of users with different fields to populate.
Thanks a lot by the way! I didn't now about the `rest_prepare_user` filter

Comment: I do not believe it is available in core, as I was digging around extensively to write this answer ;)

Comment: Maybe it's time for a ticket then!

Comment: Perhaps it is... Ill see about writing a patch when I get a little time. I would be surprised if it doesn't get snowballed though. Can only try and see ;)

Comment: I found out a smoother workaround starting from your solution. What do you think? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259700/109855